# Command name printed after executing

Tags: command-line, zsh

After running any command, the first thing to print is the name of the command itself.

[Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcYbM.png)

```
~ > echo "test" 
 echotest
~ > cd Downloads
cd%

~/Downloads >
```

Interestingly, opening tmux and running any command does it completely [normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZqye.png) without printing it again.

I'm using zsh and this started appearing today, I couldn't find anything wrong in my `./zshrc` which could be connected with that. Also, I'm using oh-my-zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the `export TERM=screen-256color` line in the `.zshrc` I added while trying to configure vim and tmux colours. In the oh-my-zsh's script `termsupport.sh` it's setting up a tab and window name depending on the TERM variable and for some reason didn't do that properly with this setting.